# Solving 'WebpackMissingModule' for create-react-app project -- specifically for 'binpacker'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm tearing my hair out about this -- I'm working on a small create-react-app project which needs to use [binpacker](https://github.com/jsmarkus/node-bin-packing) and I keep getting

> menuToData.js:2 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'binpacking'
>       at webpackMissingModule (menuToData.js:2)

I have

- removed `node_modules``
- removed `yarn.lock`
- reinstalled node modules using `yarn`
- tried using `require` instead of `import`

And nothing helps.

My `package.json` is

```
{
  "name": "something",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/core": "^10.0.10",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.18",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.4",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "binpacking": "^0.0.1",
    "bulma": "^0.7.5",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.13.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "react-spinners": "^0.5.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

and the file ('menuToData.js') where I'm importing 'binpacking' is

```
import binpacking from 'binpacking'
const Packer = binpacking.Packer;


const maxWidth = 30
const maxHeight = 20

const packer = new Packer(maxWidth,maxHeight)

export default (menu,allData) => {

  const blocks = []

  if (menu < 0 || menu > allData.length-1) return []

  const items = allData[menu].items

  for (let i = 0; i <items.length ; i++) {
    const wurst = items[i]
    for (let j = 1; j <= wurst.Quantity ; j++) {
      blocks.push({name:wurst.Name,w:wurst.Width,h:wurst.Length})
    }

  }

  if (! blocks) return []
  blocks.sort((a,b) => (b.h < a.h));
  packer.fit(blocks);

  console.log(blocks)

}
```

And here is the module in `node_modules`

[image]

And the `js/index.js` file in the module is

```
exports.GrowingPacker = require('./packer.growing.js').GrowingPacker;
exports.Packer = require('./packer.js').Packer;
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try npm uninstall binpacking, if that doesn't work, check if you have a node modules folder in the root directory of your project, delete that, delete node_modules from your project folder and npm install. I would suggest sticking to import from statements for react.

Comment: Thanks -- tried that, and it solved the first problem, but now it says 'Packer is not a constructor'.

Comment: It is probably because of this line here const packer = new Packer(maxwidth, maxheight), im not sure though, because I have never worked with this package. you can read about this error here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_constructor

Comment: Thanks -- I know that's where the error is, but I don't know why.  That's the correct usage, as per the docs...